# simple input misunderstanding in haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, input

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char
edastaNr n
   = do
      putStrLn "Anna rida:"
      line <- getLine
      if null line
         then return () 
         else do return length(line)
```

can anybody explain why the last line is incorrect and how it is possible to fix it? I do not realize.. error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[a0] -> Int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing parentheses.

```
...
else do return (length line)
```

However, there are type errors as well. What is the type of your `edasaNr` function?
It must do some IO and return an `Int`, when given an argument.

So it would be better written as:

```
edastaNr :: a -> IO Int
edastaNr n = do
    putStrLn "Anna rida:"
    line <- getLine
    if null line
     then return 0
     else return $ length line
```

which also reveals that you don't use the `n` argument (so it can have any type).

Comment: Also, since `null line` implies `length line == 0`, this means you don't even need a conditional.

Comment: The type `a -> IO Int` no longer implies you don't use the argument--at least for some meaning of "use"--`foo n = seq n $ return 0`